Next JS - meta data ESLint warning
I'm working on a Next project based on the tutorial
https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-metadata
I have this code (pretty much exactly what they have in the tutorial)
import { Providers } from './providers';
import type { Metadata } from 'next';
import '@/app/assets/css/global.css';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: ' ...',
  description:
    '...',
  icons: {
    icon: '/favicon.ico',
  },
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <Providers>
      <html lang="en">
        <body>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </Providers>
  );
}

This line is is getting a lint warning -
export const metadata: Metadata
Fast refresh only works when a file only exports components. Use a new file to share constants or functions between components.eslint(react-refresh/only-export-components)
I've added my own list of linting rules
So the question obviously is, how do you correctly use Nextjs metadata or what is the best approach to add metadata? or is it not important, should I just disable the lint rule for this line of code?
I googled, didn't really find anything

What is your actual question? You exported a non-component. The linter rule warns that this may disable 'fast refresh'. Is there a part of this that didn't make sense? Lint rules aren't perfect. There's multiple levels (warning, error) and can be disabled
